# Detecting keyboard button and play sound in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The code below actually plays sounds on each button click with vue.js.

How is it possible to detect keyboard press and play sound when DOM is ready and not when the buttons are clicked?

for example on enter play sound `v-on:keyup.13="playSound('path/to/mp3')"`

Vue documentation mostly explains html attributes, perhaps this is something that needs to be done in JS, i guess. I am new to Vue.js

Vue.js documentation on [Event Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers)

See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/errzdK).

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: ''
  },
  methods: {
    playSound (sound) {
      if(sound) {
        var audio = new Audio(sound);
        audio.play();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press a key, the keyboard event will be fired from the [active element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement) and bubble upwards. So if you want to handle *all* key presses regardless of what element has focus, then you will need to register the listener manually in code on, e.g., [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    this.onKeyDown = this.onKeyDown.bind(this);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
  },
  methods: {
    playSound (sound) {
      if(sound) {
        var audio = new Audio(sound);
        audio.play();
      }
    },
    onKeyDown(e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 65: this.playSound(sound1); break; // 'a' key
        case 66: this.playSound(sound2); break; // 'b' key
      }
    },
  }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvvKwj)

Comment: How can i find the keypress values? Why this is not working? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_key_keycode

Comment: `A` has ASCII value 65. The `keyCode` uniquely represents the key that was pressed, not the printable character it would produce (that is, `a` and `A` both have the same key code because it's the same key). There's a lot of nuance when handling keyboard events in JavaScript which I won't detail here, but you can read [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) on MDN for more info, or ask another question on StackOverflow. [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) *does* distinguish between printable characters.

Comment: One note. This is a bit slow because the sounds need to be downloaded on every request. Even if each sound is less than 40 kbs, there is a delay of 95ms on each request on heroku.

Comment: Would adding a set of switch cases be the best way to do this if you're mapping out multiple button instances and need a listener of a specific key for each button?